# Запоминание Tabs Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, html, css

Добрый вечер!

Столкнулся с проблемой сохранения нужной вкладки при обновлении страницы.
Может, кто-то сталкивался и знает, как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qeygpbrt/  - **cookies**

http://jsfiddle.net/fvcmev6t/ - **localStorage**

Comment: вроде бы настроил всё настроил под себя, но всё равно не хочет работать
http://jsfiddle.net/wxnaf15v/1/

Comment: у меня работает ваш вариант

Comment: данные то не обновляются...